# Angular Proxy Configuration

Tags: angular

I have a basic question but I cannot sort this out.
I want to connect to git hub api from my angular app but always received 400 (Bad Request).

What I did:

1. `package.json` - I added/edited `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json"`
2. I created new file `proxy.config.json`
3. Inside this file I added below `/api` configuration

   `{
       "/api": {
         "target": "https://api.github.com/",
         "secure": false
       }
   }`
4. In my `someComponent.ts` component I added:

   - `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`
   - `constructor(private http:HttpClient){}`
   - and below func:

   `somefunc(){
           return this.http.get("/api/users?per_page=10")
                   .subscribe(data =>{
                       this.datas = data
                       console.log(this.datas)
                   })
   }`

But when I tried to execute this get method in console I received:

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/users?per_page=10 400 (Bad Request)

and

> ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400,
>   statusText: "Bad Request", url:
>   "http://localhost:4200/api/users?per_page=10", ok: false, …}

Can someone help me what I did wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

For those who will have similar issue.
If your api is not hosted on localhost (external api as on my example) you need to add below lines in `proxy.config.json`

Code to add:

`"pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },`